# Шифрование RSA в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

При шифровании RSA приходится выполнять такую операцию (x^e) mod N.  Числа x,e,N могут быть 300 - значными и даже больше. Внимание вопрос. Как в JS реализовать вот это самое (x^e) mod N ? Желательно готовый пример кода, а не ссылка :-)

Comment: Пусть  будет переменная `temp = 1` умножаете её на `x` и находите остаток при деление по модулю на `N` и так `e` раз.  Есть у вас `x`, `e` и `N` большие, то не знаю насчет `js`, но в целом нужно использовать длинные числа. Алгоритм тот же, только вместо целых чисел будут длинные. Самое простое что можно придумать

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать [большие числа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) в JS?

Comment: for(i=1n,n=1n;n<=9999999n;n++){

    i=(i*136546546465465465465465449849846546516557498794654654798449464165749864n) 
% 14645654654654654654654654165465765461697941657496641n;

}

11916362535535702635802484985558488108150577998909809n



Вот это вот работает 9 секунд на моем компе.  А если цикл будет не 7-ми значное число а 300 значное?  Сдохнет любой суперкомп :-)  Надо что то другое.

Comment: Не знаю точно как в `js` большие числа устроены, но если хранить большие числа в виде 64 битных разрядов и использовать какой нибудь быстрый алгоритм умножения. Ну например Карацубы, а так же поработать над `%`, тогда все можно будет ускорить. И в `RSA` зачем использовать 300-хста символьные числа? Могу ошибаться, но вроде 1024 битного числа хватает (то есть 2 512 битных простых числа). А 1024 это всего 16 разрядов в 2^64 системе счисления. Исправьте если ошибся

Comment: 2 в 512  степени это 150 знаков. Но это в прошлом. Сейчас юзают по 300 знаков.

Comment: Ну хорошо, все равно 2 в 1024 это всего 16 разрядов, что не так много

Comment: Ну и где работающий код на JS если все так просто:? :-))

Comment: Для этого мне нужно или искать или писать библиотеку на `js` чем заниматься лично мне точно не хочется. А если вам так интересно, то со советую воспользоваться гуглом и сможете найти много интересного.

Comment: Так весь и прикол в том что искал. Готового кода на JS нету. Мне нужен исходник на JS.

Comment: Готовые примеры в ассортименте https://www.google.com/search?q=rsa%20js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через онлайн редактор код ниже у меня работает за считанные секунды:
Используется [библиотека длинных чисел](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer)

```js
let x = bigInt("136546546465465465465465449849846546516557498794654654798449464165749864");

let N = bigInt("14645654654654654654654654165465765461697941657496641");

let e = bigInt("9999999");

console.log(x.modPow(e, N).toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вот это то что надо.  Спасибо. Буду копать исходник.

Comment: @AlexShag пожалуйста, отметьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря Павел Ериков я порылся в исходниках https://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js
И вот что получилось.

```
function PowMod(x, e, N) {
    var r = 1n, base = x % N;
    while (e > 0) {
        if (base == 0n) return 0n;
        if ((e & 1n) === 1n) r = (r * base) % N;  // Если не чётное
        e = e >> 1n;
        base = (base * base) % N;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Работает ещё быстрее чем в оригинале. Так что всем кому нужно пользуйтесь на здоровье :-)